# uninitialized array passed into pipe(2)

Tags: c, operating-system, system-calls

I was looking at how to use pipe(2) on the man pages, and I don't understand a line in the source code they provided.

```
   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       int pipefd[2]; //Isn't this undefined??? so pipe(pipefd) would throw an error?
       pid_t cpid;
       char buf;

       if (argc != 2) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
           perror("pipe");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       cpid = fork();
       if (cpid == -1) {
           perror("fork");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (cpid == 0) {    /* Child reads from pipe */
           close(pipefd[1]);          /* Close unused write end */

           while (read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1) > 0)
               write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);

           write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
           close(pipefd[0]);
           _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

       } else {            /* Parent writes argv[1] to pipe */
           close(pipefd[0]);          /* Close unused read end */
           write(pipefd[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
           close(pipefd[1]);          /* Reader will see EOF */
           wait(NULL);                /* Wait for child */
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       }
   }
```

I thought non-static function variables are just whatever is in memory? Why does this source code work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pipefd` array serves as output argument here, so there is no need to initialize it. `pipe` function **writes** into it.

Answer (score 0):

Array pipefd returns 2 fds that refer to the end of pipes. Here, the pipefd[1] refers to the write end of the pipe and the pipefd[0] refers to the read end of the pipe.

In the above program:

1. The pipefd[1] is not used in child and hence it is closed. Data is read from pipefd[0] by child.

Note that the read blocks if pipe is empty and the write blocks if pipe is full.

2. The pipefd[0] is not used in parent and hence it is closed. Data is written into pipefd[1] by parent.

Also note that as pipe is unidirectional, the data written to the write end (pipefd[1]) of pipe is buffered by kernel until it is read from read end of the pipe(pipefd[0]).